# Column Width in GWT CellTable Text Column

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I am trying to set Constant Column width to all column in Gwt Celltable,

How to achieve this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the column width with the [setColumnWidth](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#setColumnWidth%28com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column,%20double,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit%29) method.